# React-Native SagaTester "Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, redux-saga

I've recently made some changes to a codebase using redux-saga, however when running the unit tests, one saga test is consistently failing, despite me not having touched any code relating to this function, or any of its functionality.

This test was previously working, and continues to pass on the master branch. I can't figure out what I've changed that has broken this test, however I feel it's likely due to the race condition being improperly handled.

So far I've attempted various things, including changing the timeout and the jest timers etc. However it doesn't seem to be mocking out the timeout scenario.

**Code:**

The Saga:

```
function* getCartTransactionStatus() {
   const authorizationHeader = yield select(getAuthorizationHeader);
   const headers = yield getHeaders(authorizationHeader);

    const { response, cancel, timeout } = yield race({
      response: call(checkCartTransactionStatus, headers),
      cancel: take(CART_TRANSACTION_STATUS_POLLING_CANCEL),
      timeout:  delay(1200000)
    })
    if(response)
    {
        yield put(cartActions.getCartTransactionComplete())
    }
    else {
      yield put(cartActions.getCartTransactionIncomplete());
    }
```

The Test:

```
  test("get cart status failure on required transactionsStatus not found", async () => {
    instance.mockReturnValueOnce({
      data: {
        transactionStatus: "NOT_CLEARED_BASKET"
      },
    })

    sagaTester.dispatch(cartActions.getCartTransactionStatus())
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(120000)
    const action = await sagaTester.waitFor(CART_TRANSACTION_INCOMPLETE)
    expect(action).toEqual({
      type: CART_TRANSACTION_INCOMPLETE,
    })
  })
```

The Error:

```
  ● Cart Transaction Status Saga › get cart status failure on required transactionsStatus not found

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      242 |   })
      243 | 
    > 244 |   test("get cart status failure on required transactionsStatus not found", async () => {
          |   ^
      245 |     instance.mockReturnValueOnce({
      246 |       data: {
      247 |         transactionStatus: "NOT_CLEARED_BASKET"

      at Spec (node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Spec.js:85:20)
      at Suite.test (sagas/cart.test.js:244:3)
      at Object.describe (sagas/cart.test.js:207:1)
```

Comment: What's `sagaTester`? Where does it come from?

Comment: @slideshowp2 
Apologies, that is a good question!
It's imported from redux-saga-tester